# Silverlight toolkit theme not applied to label

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

Do I have to do something special to the Label control from the Silverlight toolkit to get the current themed applied?

When looking at the Theme Browser on the [demo page](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) it appears as though labels should be turning white in the expression dark theme, but it's staying black for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine for me. You might have an implicit or explicit Label style that overwrites it.

**Edit:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
        <Grid>
            <sdk:Label Content="label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </toolkit:ExpressionDarkTheme>
</Grid>
```

Comment: +1 for checking.  I'm fairly sure I don't have any styles overwriting the label's theme's style.  Could I trouble you to post the xaml you're using to produce the label and, more importantly, to set the theme?  There seem to be many ways of setting a theme, and they all work slightly differently.

Comment: Yep, thanks.  Looks like you have to use the ThemeContainer to get this to work.  I had something like `<sdk:Theme ThemeUri="....ExpressionDark...">` which does not seem to style the label  thanks again